# 'immediately before', 'right before' and 'just before'

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-choice

What is the difference (if any) between immediately before, right before and just before ?

What is the most suitable one to use in this sentence:

> The paragraph ..... before the image.

Comment: This involves the separate meanings of *immediately*, *right* and *just* in context. So it will be context dependent. Your example is referring to position, so I would just use "The paragraph *above* the image."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because none of the proposed options are appropriate for the suggested sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence should be: "The paragraph preceding the image".

In general, "immediately before", "right before" and "just before" have similar meanings.